# Parse string with propositional formula in CNF to DIMACS nested int list in haskell

Tags: haskell, satisfiability

I would like to parse string with a propositional formula in CNF to DIMACS, thus a nested int list in haskell. The format is suitable for the haskell picosat bindings that seem to be more performant then other options for SAT solving.

The problem is that my code that implemented this is too complicated and now I am looking for a possible bug that is not obvious to find.

(My approach was to use the haskell hatt package, change the package so it uses Strings instead of single characters for variables names, parse the expression with hatt and then convert the resulting expression to the DIMACS format.)

I want to parse a string that represents a propositional formula in CNF notation (see example below). The result shoud be a nested list of ints. Thus the result should be suitable for `solveAll` that is part of the [haskell picosat bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/picosat-0.1.0.2/docs/Picosat.html).

Input:

```
-- "&" ... conjunction
-- "|" ... disjunction
-- "-" ... not operator

let myCNF = "GP  &  (-GP  |  Ma)  &  (-Ma  |  GP)  &  (-Ma  |  TestP)  &  (-Ma  |  Alg)  &  (-Ma  |  Src)  &  (-Ma  |  Hi)  &  (-Ma  |  Wg | X | Y) & -Z"
```

Result:

```
-- DIMACS format
-- every Variable (e.g., "GP") gets a number, say GP gets the int num 1
-- in case of not GP (i.e., "-GP") the int number representing the variable is negative, thus -1

-- Note: I hope I didn't do a type
let myresult = [[1], [-1, 2], [-2, 1], [-2, 3], [-2, 3], [-2, 5], [-2, 6], [-2, 7, 8, 9], [-10]]

let myvars = ["GP", "Ma", "TestP", "Alg", "Src", "Hi", "Wg", "X", "Y", "Z"]

-- or alternativly the variables are stored in an associative array
let varOtherWay = (1, GP), (2, Ma) (3, TestP), (4, Alg), (5, Src), (6, Hi), (7, Wg), (8, X), (9, Y), (10, Z)
```

Comment: So where is your attempt?

Comment: I used a very complicated route and copy and pasted the original hatt package from https://github.com/beastaugh/hatt and adapted it. But I didn't use git, so I can even paste a git diff here. I am not sure posting a zip file somwhere helps. If I did it again I would perhaps just split the string. However I have the feeling that this can be done like in 3-4 lines with parsec but I am not yet familiar enough to to use it in a way that I trust my code. I still have a lot to learn regarding haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need parsec to read statements in CNF, you can extract the variables with `map (splitOn "|") . splitOn "&"` - the rest is just assigning integers to variables:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M 
import Data.List.Split
import Control.Monad.State 

deleteMany c [] = []
deleteMany c (x:xs) 
  | x`elem`c  =     deleteMany c xs
  | otherwise = x : deleteMany c xs

parseStatement :: String -> ( [[Int]] , M.Map Int String )
parseStatement = 
 f . flip runState (M.empty, 1) . mapM (mapM (readVar . toVar)) . varsOf . deleteMany "() "
  where 
    f (r, (m, _)) = (r , M.fromList $ map (uncurry (flip (,))) $ M.toList m)

    varsOf = map (splitOn "|") . splitOn "&"

    toVar ('-':v) = (True , v)
    toVar v       = (False, v)

    readVar (b,v) = do 
      (m, c) <- get 
      case M.lookup v m of 
        Nothing -> put (M.insert v c m, c+1) >> return (neg b c)
        Just n  ->                              return (neg b n)

    neg True  = negate
    neg False = id
```

Maybe the parsec version is still interesting for error handling or being integrated into a larger parser:

```
parseStatement = parse statement "" . deleteMany " "

statement = sepBy1 clause (char '&')

clause = between (char '(') (char ')') x <|> x
  where x = sepBy1 var (char '|')

var = do
  n <- maybe False (const True) <$> optionMaybe (char '-')
  v <- many1 (noneOf "&|-() ")
  return (n, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain the picosat bindings you mentioned. After seeing this question, I've added a new `picologic` package to Hackage that builds on top of `picosat` to parse and convert with propositional formulas and feed them to the SAT solver.

```
import Picologic

p, q, r :: Expr
p = readExpr "~(A | B)"
q = readExpr "(A | ~B | C) & (B | D | E) & (D | F)"
r = readExpr "(φ <-> ψ)"

ps = ppExprU p
-- ¬(A ∨ B)
qs = ppExprU q
-- ((((A ∨ ¬B) ∨ C) ∧ ((B ∨ D) ∨ E)) ∧ (D ∨ F))
rs = ppExprU (cnf r)
-- ((φ ∧ (φ ∨ ¬ψ)) ∧ ((ψ ∨ ¬φ) ∧ ψ))

main :: IO ()
main = solveProp p >>= putStrLn . ppSolutions
-- ¬A ¬B
-- ¬A B
-- A ¬B
```

See: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/picologic